# JDBC MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/facts", "root", "");
int x = s.size();
for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO facts.facts (Sno, Description) VALUES ("+ i +","+ s.get(i) + ")";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

I am getting this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'than 1/3 of adults and over 12.5 million children and teens in the US are obese.' at line 1.

The first string of ArrayList s is "More than 1/3 of adults and over 12.5 million children and teens in the US are obese. In the last 30 years, obesity in children and teens has nearly tripled."

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of your error is likely that the string you are trying to insert is not being properly quoted.  You *could* try the following to fix that:

```
"'" + s.get(i) + "'"
```

However, you should really use a prepared statement here:

```
for (int i=0; i < x; i++) {
    String selectSQL = "INSERT INTO facts.facts (Sno, Description) VALUES (?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, i);
    ps.setString(2, s.get(i));
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Benefits of using prepared statements include:

- string quotation/escaping is handled for you automatically
- protection against SQL injection
- query is easier to read and maintain, as SQL language is clearly demarcated from your Java app code

Comment: **Still Showing Error:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1

Comment: Strange...it should be working.  Can you try running the raw `INSERT` query on MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: don't use the parameter `sql` in the call to `ps.executeUpdate()`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Thanks...it helps to test code before posting it here (which I almost never do with JDBC stuff due to overhead involved).